# Taking imaginary time to show damping relation in path integral formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, partition-function, wick-rotation

I'm having trouble with a step in the reasoning in pg.9 of Bailin & Love - Introduction to gauge field theory:

To find the ground-state to ground-state amplitude we have a term:(given a basis of energy eigenstates $|n\rangle$; given dinamical variable $q$ ; given $\hat{H}|0\rangle = 0$):
$$\langle q'',t''|q_+,t_+\rangle=\sum_n\langle q'',t''|n\rangle\langle n|q_+,t_+\rangle=\sum_ne^{-iE_n(t''-t_+)/\hbar}\langle q''|n\rangle\langle n|q_+\rangle.$$
Now, the authors in eq. (2.31) take $t''\rightarrow-i\infty$ and reason:

> "Then the decaying exponentials ensure that only the contribuition from the ground state $|0\rangle$ survives".

I can see that as $t$ goes to infinity, the non-zero eigenstates give an rapid rotating amplitude such that near-time intervals cancel out, but how is this allowed to take $t$ to imaginary infinity and after showing the result, to come back to real $t$?

A page after this, it is used the wick rotation to take a imaginary exponential to a damping one, but it uses simple integration substituition, that for me is OK.

Comment: Hi Acephalus. Could you elaborate? The Wick rotations on p. 9 and p. 10 are essentially equivalent. B&L do not "come back to real $t$" in this argument.

Comment: Sure! I think I don't understand why it is allowed to take $t$ in a imaginary direction and what is the meaning of it. Many other textbooks including Pesking goes like $t \rightarrow (1-i\epsilon)\infty$ and similar directions.Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Acephalus It is just a matter of computational convenience (in your case, you get a damping factor times a phase, which is physically irrelevant) and/or explicitly showing analogies/differences with Euclidean space. As far as I am aware, thinking of the physical significance of such artifices almost always leads to warped visions of physical phenomena.